# Why can't a prime number p be the base of a maximal ideal of R[x]? R[x] is a polynomial ring.

Tags: ring-theory

Come to think about it, if you have R(x).p, Q(x).p, etc, all these can be members of the aforementioned ideal.

The textbook I'm referring to says only linear polynomials of the form (x-a) can be the base for a maximal ideal of R[x].

Comment: Does your textbook say the polynomial ring is over a field?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by R(x).p? Also, if $R$ is just an arbitrary ring, what do you mean by a prime number $p$ being the base of a maximal ideal of $R[x]$?

Comment: @AndrewO'Desky Presumably p is a prime element in the base ring R, and apparently the textbook says that the only principal maximal ideals are those generated by linear polynomials.

Comment: @anon- No. The textbook just states that it is a polynomial ring.

Comment: Again: what does it mean " to be the base of a maximal ideal "? Do you mean to be " the generator of (principal, then) maximal ideal "?

Comment: My basic question is that if the base (p) in R[x] can't be part of a larger ideal, which it presumably can't, why shouldn't it be considered a maximal ideal?

@DonAntonio- Yes. The generator. Sorry.

Comment: Well then assuming anon's assumptions, I suppose the book must be implying that the only prime elements of $R[x]$ are precisely the linear polynomials. Also if assuming by R(x).p you mean the set of products of this prime element with the field of fractions of $R[x]$, I don't see most of those would be contained in your ideal, considering they would have denominators, in general. If when you said a prime number p, you had the particular example in mind that $R$ was the integers, I don't think such an ideal $(p)$ would be maximal, since one can simply consider $(p,x^2)$.

Comment: $(p)$ is the member of the larger ideal $(p,X)$.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question in the title:

Let $p\in R$ be a prime element, so that $R/(p)$ is a domain. Then consider $I=(p)R[X]$, the ideal generated by $p$ in $R[X]$, and note that
$$
R[X]/I\simeq \left(R/(p)\right)[X]
$$
is not a field, hence $I$ isn't maximal in $R[X]$.

Answer (score 0):

A maximal ideal in a ring $S$ is defined to be a proper ideal $I$ such that if $J$ is another ideal of $S$ satisfying $I\subseteq J\subseteq S$ then $I=J$ or $J=S$.  Now, if $p$ is a prime element of the ring $S=R[X]$, then $p$ is not a unit, so the polynomial $X$ is not contained in $(p)$ (as if $sp=X$ then $s$ must be a polynomial of the form $rX$ with $rs=1$, which is a contradiction).

Therefore, the ideal $(p,X)=\{\textrm{polynomials whose constant term is a multiple of }p\}$ contains $(p)$, and is contained in $R[X]$, but it is not equal to either of them.  So $(p)$ is not maximal.

Comment: True. (p) is a part of the bigger ideal (p,X). But then again, if one says (x-a) is the maximal ideal of R[x], can't I say that is again part of the bigger ideal (x-a,x-b), and hence not maximal? If I'm being naive, could you kindly explain where I'm going wrong, or maybe drop a helpful link?

Comment: I'm following the book "Algebra" by Michael Artin, btw. [Here] (https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~sjw47/Lecture1-3.pdf) I read that (p,X) is the maximal ideal for R[x], and not (x-a). I don't understand how (p,X) is not in turn part of the bigger ideal (a,p,X).

Comment: To answer your first question: first of all, the ideal $(X-a)$ is maximal in $R[X]$ if and only if $R$ is a field.  (Indeed, if $(X-a)$ **is** maximal, it means that for any $r\in R$, $r\neq 0$, the ideal $(X-a,r)$ must be the whole ring $R[X]$, since it strictly contains $(X-a)$ and $(X-a)$ is maximal.  So in particular, $1\in (X-a,r)$, so $br+c(X-a)=1$, for some $b,c\in R$.  Clearly, $c=0$, meaning that $br=1$; i.e., $r$ has a multiplicative inverse.  So $R$ is a field.)

Comment: If $R$ is a field, we want to show that $(X-a)$ is maximal for any $a\in R$.  First of all, your 'counterexample' of $(X-a,X-b)$ does not work: remember that an ideal has to be closed under addition: this means that $(X-a)-(X-b)=b-a\in (X-a,X-b)$, and since R is a field, $(b-a)$ has an inverse, so $1\in (X-a,X-b)$, so $(X-a,X-b)=R[X]$.  I'll leave it up to you to prove that $(X-a)$ is indeed maximal in $R[X]$ if $R$ is a field: the proof uses similar ideas.

Comment: $p+X\in(p,X)$, yet $p+X$ is not a multiple of $p$ and has a constant term (it also has a linear term, but I think you never meant that in the first place).

Comment: To answer your second question: in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, $(p,X)$ is indeed a maximal ideal for any prime $p$.  If $a$ is another prime, with $a\neq p$, then $(p,X)$ is strictly contained in $(a,p,X)$, but that doesn't mean that $(p,X)$ isn't maximal, since it turns out that $(a,p,X)$ is actually the whole ring.  **Proof:** since $a,p$ are coprime, we have $ra+sp=1$, for some $r,s\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $1\in (a,p,X)$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen - thanks, corrected now

Comment: @Donkey_2009: Your arguments can be somewhat simplified using $R[X]/(X-a)\cong R$, valid for any commutative ring $R$ and any $a\in R$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen - you're right, and that's in fact how I came up with my proofs.  I'd just rather not confuse the OP by using results ($I$ maximal if and only if $R/I$ is a field) that (s)he has seen, but might not be fluent with yet.

Comment: @Donkey_2009- thanks!! This truly does clear some things! I suppose the motivation behind your proof (regarding (X-a,X-b)) is that if we can create a term without X, then knowing that its inverse is there in the field R, we can prove that the ideal is the whole of R[X]. 
What about (X-a, X^2) though? 
Thanks tons for your previous help, all.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan - no problem!  For the case $(X-a,X^2)$ we can create a constant polynomial as follows: $X^2-(X+a)(X-a)=a^2$.  In general, if we've got the ideal $(P,X-a)$ for $F$ a field and $P$ a polynomial in $F[X]$, we use the *division algorithm* for polynomials (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).  This tells us that $P=Q(X-a)+R$, where either $R=0$ or $R$ has degree strictly less than that of $(X-a)$.  If $R=0$, that means that $P=Q(X-a)$, so $(P,X-a)=(X-a)$.  If $R\neq 0$, then we know that the degree of $R$ is less than that of $(X-a)$; i.e., $R$ is a constant.

Comment: (so then $R=P-Q(X-a)$, so $R\in (P,X-a)$, and since $R$ is a constant in $F$, it has an inverse, so $1\in (P,X-a)$, so $(P,X-a)=F[X]$.)

Comment: Thanks all. Now I fully understand the concept. I'd just like to say one thing. If R is a ring and not a field, and p is a prime number in it, then (p) will be a maximal ideal, which was my original question. Only when R is a field that only irreducible polynomials can be generators for maximal ideals of R[x]. Obviously when R is the field of compex numbers, as a result of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, only linear polynomials of the form x-a can act as the generators of maximal polynomials. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes - I think you've got it, except for one point.  If $R$ isn't a field, and $p$ is a prime in $R$, then $(p)=\{\textrm{polynomials that are multiples of }p\}$ is not maximal, since it is contained in the larger ideal $(p,X)=\{\textrm{polynomials whose constant term is a multiple of }p\}$ (which is maximal).  In fact, $R[X]$ contains maximal ideals with arbitrarily many generators: for example, $(p^2,pX,X^2)$ and $(p^3,p^2X,pX^2,X^3)$ are both maximal (though showing that they're not generated by a smaller number of generators isn't completely trivial).

Comment: @Donkey_2009- I was thinking of the very same thing last night after posting the comment. Correction noted. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume calling $p$ a "prime number" implies that it is an element of $R$. Then it cannot generate a maximal ideal because $R[X]/(p)\cong (R/(p))[X]$ is either the trivial ring (if $p$ is invertible) or a polynomial ring; in either case it is not a field.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ \rm\:n\in R,\ (n)\:$ maximal in $\rm\:R[x]\:\Rightarrow\: (n) = (1)$

**Proof** $\ $ If $\rm\  x\in (n)\:$ then $\rm\:x = n f\,\stackrel{x=1}{\Rightarrow} 1 = n\,f(1)\:\Rightarrow\: (n) = (1).\:$  Else $\rm\: x\not\in (n),\:$ so $\rm\,(n)\,$ maximal $\rm\:\Rightarrow\:(x,n) = (1),\:$ so $\rm\:xf+ng = 1\stackrel{x=0}{\Rightarrow}n g(0) = 1\:\Rightarrow\:(n)=(1). $

Comment: This is actually a proof that $(n)$ is never a maximal ideal, since $(1)$ is the whole ring $R[x]$ and is therefore not maximal, since it isn't proper.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Yes, that's the point!